# Why UIBarbuttonItem is not working in Swift while code is written well?

Tags: xcode, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I have written the same behaviour in two ways. The first one, doesn't work:

```
var barbutton = (left) ? navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem : navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem
barbutton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

opposite to:

```
if (left) {
     navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
} else {
     navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
}
```

What is the difference?

Comment: Perhaps you thought that in the first case, `barbutton` is some kind of "reference" that can be used to set `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`. That is not the case, the second line simply *overwrites* the local variable and no navigation item is set at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Martin points out, the two code sequences are very different in function.

The first sets `barbutton` to the contents of either `leftBarButtonItem` or `rightBarButtonItem` and then discards that value and sets (the temporary variable) to a newly created button.

The second sets either `leftBarButtonItem` or `rightBarButtonItem`, depending on `left` to a newly created button.

There really isn't much way to shorten your code and still achieve the desired effect (without also obscuring the code).

You could use:

```
(left ? navigationItem.setLeftBarButtonItem : navigationItem.setRightBarButtonItem)(UIBarButtonItem(customView: button), animated: false)
```

But that's just weird.